# Libreoffice on GPD Pocket 3 (7 inch laptop). How to navigate to the bottom of options dialogue?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a GPD Pocket 3. This device has a rather small screen. Under ubuntu 23.10 when running Libreoffice and entering tools options, I get the following screen:
[image]

On my bigger laptop (albeit on Kubuntu 23.10) I get:

[image]

How could I reconfigure Libreoffice to get the full picture on the smaller device. Alternatively,  how could I see the lower part of the screen?

PS: Screen resolution is 1920 * 1200 on both screens. On the first one settings a set to scale 200% (which works well for me in most circumstances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Alt` + `Left Mouse Button` to move the window around. If a window can be resized at all (not sure about this one), `Alt` + `Right Mouse Button` can be used to resize it.

Comment: Not very beautiful, but it works. I am experimenting with fractional scaling to achieve a better result. Unfortunately the window in question is not resizable.